# UIWebView screen taps in area cease to work after showing then hiding a UIView overlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have been working on an app that features a full screen UIWebView which contains a HTML based application. It features a working QR code scan using a native bridge between JS and Native Obj-C code. Tapping a button launches this UIView that is about half the size of the overall display, as an overlay, inside this you see the video feed and when a QR code is detected it passes the code back and the UIView is closed. That works a treat.

However the UIWebview then suffers from an odd issue, any elements that would have been underneath the UIView then become untappable. It's as if there is a ghost of the UIView still present.

Any ideas why this could be occurring?

```
- (void)handleCall:(NSString*)functionName callbackId:(int)callbackId args:(NSArray*)args
{
    if ([functionName isEqualToString:@"setBackgroundColor"]) {

       ....... SNIP ........
}
else if ([functionName isEqualToString:@"scanQRCode"]) {

    _viewPreview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(256, 192, 512, 384)];

    [self addSubview:self.viewPreview];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:_viewPreview];

    _captureSession = nil;

    if (!_isReading) {
      if ([self startReading]) {
        NSLog(@"Read barcode: %@", @"started");
      }
    }
    else{
      [self stopReading];

      [_viewPreview removeFromSuperview];
      [_viewPreview release];


    }

    _isReading = !_isReading;
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"Unimplemented method '%@'",functionName);
   [uniReader requestSwipe];
   [self returnResult:callbackId args:nil];  
  }
}

- (BOOL)startReading {
  NSError *error;

  AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

  AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];

  if (!input) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return NO;
  }

  _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
  [_captureSession addInput:input];

  AVCaptureMetadataOutput *captureMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
  [_captureSession addOutput:captureMetadataOutput];

  dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue;
  dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
  [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];
  [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];

  _videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc]    initWithSession:_captureSession];
 [_videoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
 [_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:_viewPreview.layer.bounds];
 [_viewPreview.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];
 // Since the app is landscape only, it is necessary to rotate the preview view to match
 [_videoPreviewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];
 // Start video capture.
 [_captureSession startRunning];

 return YES;
```

}

```
 -(void)stopReading{
 [_captureSession stopRunning];
 _captureSession = nil;
    NSLog(@"Read barcode: %@", @"Stop scanning");

 [_videoPreviewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

}

```
   -(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput    didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:  (AVCaptureConnection *)connection{

 // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
 if (metadataObjects != nil && [metadataObjects count] > 0) {
 // Get the metadata object.
 AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObj = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *barcodeString = metadataObj.stringValue;
 NSLog(@"Detected QR: %@", barcodeString);

NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setQR('%@')", barcodeString];

if ([[metadataObj type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {
  // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text,
  // stop reading and change the bar button item's title and the flag's value.
  // Everything is done on the main thread.

  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

  _isReading = NO;
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject:javaScript waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

}
 }

@end

Comment: Can you post the relevant code for showing/hiding the `UIView`?

Comment: Sounds like the overlay leaves a full screen transparent view over the top. How do you add and remove your overlay?

Comment: Added the rest of the code, minus a few other methods and imports, just to keep it as brief as possible.

Comment: Is scanQRCode called twice: once to add and once to remove the overlay? If so then you always add a new overlay view at the start. Any `stopReading` will remove the running video from its superview (the original overlay) then remove the latest overlay from the screen. This will leave the original overlay window with no content which could be your issue?

Comment: Thanks Rory, you were spot on there. Have now solved my problem.

Comment: Fab. Posted as an answer if you would be so good as to accept it 8^).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is scanQRCode called twice: once to add and once to remove the overlay? If so then you always add a new overlay view at the start. Any stopReading will remove the running video from its superview (the original overlay) then remove the latest overlay from the screen. This will leave the original overlay window with no content which could be your issue?